# Laravel Policies - specifying the policy to use

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Can I explicitly specify the particular policy to use along with the method, instead of using the policy that pertains to the object of the second parameters?

I would like to do something like this:

```
$this->authorize('FeatureNamePolicy', 'isEnabled');
```

the parameters are:

1. Name of the policy
2. Method of the policy

Instead of using the parameters:

1. Method name within the policy
2. Object (determines the policy used)

Answer (score 0):

I did it with this

```
$this->authorize('featureIsEnabled', sheetPolicy::class);
```